# Linear Algebra Question: Prove that no proper subset spans

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to prove that

"**S** is a basis for linear space **L** if and only if it is a minimal spanning set for **L**. In other words **S** is a basis for **L** if and only if **S** spans **L** and no proper subset of **S** spans **L**."

I've got the general setup for this proof, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to prove that no proper subset of S spans L. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If a proper subset S' of S spanned L, you can pick s in S' \ S and write it as a linear combination of elements of S'.

Comment: Would that then contradict the linear independence of S then? Sorry, proofs are really not my thing and I'm struggling with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is that all elements of the basis must be linearly independent.

Proof outline:

Assume that $S$ is a basis for $L$, and $S' \subsetneq S$ also spans $L$.
Then, since the elements of $A = (S' \setminus S)$ are in $L$, the elements of $A$ can be written as linear combinations of the elements in $S'$.
This contradicts the independence of $S$ (the basis).

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful and I very much appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you believe my response has sufficiently answered your question, I'd appreciate it if you would click the green check mark to the left of my response.  This marks my response as "accepted," and lets others know that this question has a sufficient response.  `:)`